# How to populate and group by populated field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to implement vatting schema, and I created mongoose schema as below,
and I want to populate votes and group by `chosen`, where chosen is a `participantId`.
Query bellow returns all votes ungrouped.

```
var ParticipantSchema = new Schema({
   firstName: String,
   lastName: String
});

var VoteSchema = new Schema({
   userId:{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
   competitionId:{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Competition'},
   chosen:String,
});

var CompetitionSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   type: String,
   votes:[{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Vote'}],
   participants: [ParticipantSchema]
});

var Competition = mongoose.model('Competition', CompetitionSchema);
var Vote = mongoose.model('Vote', VoteSchema);



    //query 
    var name = decodeURIComponent(req.query.name);

    var options = [{
        $group: {
            _id: '$chosen',
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }, {
        "$sort": {"count": -1}
    }];
    Competition.findOne({name: name})
        .populate({path: 'votes', select: 'chosen', options: options})
        .exec(function (err, result) {
                 console.log(result)
         });
```

And It's prints all votes ungrouped

```
 ...,
 "votes": [
  {
    "_id": "583d432c7ca0854f9c81a898",
    "chosen": "583b0afc0cc87818f02fed2f"
  },
  {
    "_id": "583d6af17e6b7e2b98c01f3b",
    "chosen": "583b07da0cc87818f02fed2e" //the same
  },
  {
    "_id": "583d6b147e6b7e2b98c01f3c",
    "chosen": "583b07da0cc87818f02fed2e" //the same
  }
],
 ...
```

Any solution or suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: May be this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231022/mongoose-how-to-group-by-and-populate


$lookup - for mongoDB 3.2

Comment: You can't do that with the populate method, only applicable with the aggregation framework. You may want to consider the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) operator to achieve this.