# Mongoose: Group by Object id and push in one array, sort by createdAt, populate all objects and paginate it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pagination, aggregate

This is an example of getList of Arrivals by 10 items per page:

```
router.get('/arrivals', isAuthenticated, async (request, response, next) => {
  jsonPreProcessor.response = response;

  const resPerPage = 10;
  const page = request.query.page || 1;

  Arrival.find({})
    .populate({
      path: 'product',
      populate: {
        path: 'type'
      }
    })
    .select('-__v')
    .skip((resPerPage * page) - resPerPage)
    .limit(resPerPage).then(arrivals => {
      Arrival.countDocuments({}).then(numberOfResults => {
        return jsonPreProcessor.paginate(arrivals, page, Math.ceil(numberOfResults / resPerPage), numberOfResults);
      }).catch(error => {
        return jsonPreProcessor.error(error.message);
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      return jsonPreProcessor.error(error.message);
    });
});
```

And this is an output:

```
{
  "time": "2020-01-16T10:11:22.588Z",
  "message": "success",
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "list": [
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "discount": 0,
        "_id": "5e0db80a37dd4437b4329960",
        "product": {
          "_id": "5e0cecaaa9a5cc2c7c62e379",
          "title": "Ортопедический",
          "type": {
            "_id": "5ddcbc4685e53838dc564a44",
            "title": "fsdkjhfs",
            "createdAt": "2019-11-26T05:46:46.797Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-11-26T05:46:46.797Z",
            "alt": "fsdkjhfs",
            "__v": 0
          },
          ...
          "mode": "simple",
          "createdAt": "2020-01-01T19:02:02.840Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T19:02:02.840Z",
          "alt": "ortopedicheskij",
          "__v": 0
        },
        ...
        "sellPrice": 6,
        "minSellPrice": 0,
        "createdAt": "2020-01-02T09:29:46.688Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T09:30:26.126Z"
      },
      ... // And other 9 items
    ],
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pages": 2,
    "numberOfResults": 16,
    "incompleteResults": true
  },
  "type": null
}
```

All those are arrivals, and as you see arrivals have product. Some arrivals can have same product (by id) 
**My problem is to group arrivals which have same product. (sorted by first item of arrivals array) populate all objects.. and paginate.** I use aggregate, and unfortunately I don't have any idea how to use it (first of all aggregate's output is random) with pagination and of course output is not what I need. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231022/mongoose-how-to-group-by-and-populate) as solving of my problem.

```
router.get('/arrivalls', isAuthenticated, async (request, response, next) => {
  jsonPreProcessor.response = response;

  Arrival.aggregate(
    [
      // This is not working (may be it's not working in array)
      // {
      //   "$sort": {
      //     "createdAt": 1
      //   }
      // },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$product",
          "arrivals": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      },
      // {
      //   "$lookup": {
      //     "from": "arrivals",
      //     "localField": "product",
      //     "foreignField": "_id",
      //     "as": "product"
      //   }
      // },
      // {
      //   "$unwind": {
      //     "path": "$arrivals"
      //   }
      // }
    ]
  ).then(arrivals => {
      // console.log(arrivals);
      return jsonPreProcessor.success(arrivals);
    }).catch(error => {
      return jsonPreProcessor.error(error.message);
    });
});
```

Output should be like:

```
  "data": {
    "list": [
    {
      "_id": "5e1d5dba611485397cfb0386",
      "arrivals": [
        {
          "_id": "5e1d5e26611485397cfb0387",
          "quantity": 6,
          "discount": 0,
          "product": {
            "_id": "5e1d5dba611485397cfb0386",
            ... // etc
          },
          "sellPrice": 5000,
          "minSellPrice": 4500,
          "createdAt": "2020-01-14T06:22:30.366Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T09:14:13.824Z",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "5e1ff4d15d059430e8405f94",
          "quantity": 2,
          "discount": 0,
          "product": {
            "_id": "5e1d5dba611485397cfb0386",
            ... // etc
          },
          "sellPrice": 7000,
          "minSellPrice": 6000,
          "comment": "",
          "createdAt": "2020-01-16T05:29:53.907Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-01-16T05:29:53.907Z",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e1d84884d387d2334a7e9d9",
      "arrivals": [
        {
          // etc...
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "currentPage": 1,
  "pages": 2,
  "numberOfResults": 16,
  "incompleteResults": true
},
"type": null
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.. And here is grouping, sorting, populating and paginating of list.

```
  const resPerPage = 10;
  const page = request.query.page || 1;

  Arrival.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'products',
          localField: 'product',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'product'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$product",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'branchdans',
          localField: 'branch',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'branch'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$branch",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'colors',
          localField: 'color',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'color'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$color",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'types',
          localField: 'product.type',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'product.type'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$product.type",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'subcategories',
          localField: 'product.subcategory',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'product.subcategory'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$product.subcategory",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'categories',
          localField: 'product.subcategory.category',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'product.subcategory.category'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$product.subcategory.category",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'countries',
          localField: 'product.country',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'product.country'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$product.country",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'manufacturers',
          localField: 'product.manufacturer',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'product.manufacturer'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$product.manufacturer",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          "_id": "$product._id",
          "sizes": {
            "$first": "$product.sizes"
          },
          "title": {
            "$first": "$product.title"
          },
          "type": {
            "$first": "$product.type"
          },
          "subcategory": {
            "$first": "$product.subcategory"
          },
          "country": {
            "$first": "$product.country"
          },
          "manufacturer": {
            "$first": "$product.manufacturer"
          },
          "description": {
            "$first": "$product.description"
          },
          "comment": {
            "$first": "$product.comment"
          },
          "mode": {
            "$first": "$product.mode"
          },
          "createdAt": {
            "$first": "$product.createdAt"
          },
          "updatedAt": {
            "$first": "$product.updatedAt"
          },
          "alt": {
            "$first": "$product.alt"
          },
          arrivals: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
          },
          "date": {
            $last: "$createdAt"
          }
        },
      },
      {
        $unset: "arrivals.product"
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          "date": 1
        }
      },
      {
        $skip: (resPerPage * page) - resPerPage
      },
      {
        $limit: resPerPage
      }
    ]
  ).then(arrivals => {

      Arrival.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            "_id": "$product",
            arrivals: {
              $push: "$$ROOT"
            },
            "date": {
              "$last": "$createdAt"
            }
          },
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "date": 1
          }
        },
        {
          $count: "numberOfResults"
        }
      ]).then(countArrivals => {
        if(countArrivals.length === 0){
          return jsonPreProcessor.error('Ошибка при высчитывании прибытий товаров');
        }
        // Todo make more practise
        return jsonPreProcessor.paginate(arrivals, page, Math.ceil(countArrivals[0].numberOfResults / resPerPage), countArrivals[0].numberOfResults);
      }).catch(error => {
        return jsonPreProcessor.error(error.message);
      });

      // return jsonPreProcessor.success(arrivals);
    }).catch(error => {
      return jsonPreProcessor.error(error.message);
    });
```